# Use input value as an array variable

Tags: php

I'm totally new to php. I'm trying to echo the value of an input field into a an array but it doesn't seem to work.e.g echo the value of hidden-input as the value for origin in the array. How can I achieve this?

```
<form method="post">
    <!-- Set type -> Hidden, if you want to make that input field hidden.
You really should use better "names" for the input fields -->

// I populate the value with jQuery  //

    <input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" name="from" value="">

</form>
<?php 


    $params = array(
        'origin'        =>  $_post['from'],
        'destination'   => um_user('postal_zip_code'),
        'sensor'        => 'true',
        'units'         => 'imperial'
    );


    $params_string='';
    // Join parameters into URL string
    foreach($params as $var => $val){
        $params_string .= '&' . $var . '=' . urlencode($val);  
    }

    // Request URL
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?".ltrim($params_string, '&');

    // Make our API request
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Parse the JSON response
    $directions = json_decode($return);

    //echo"<pre>";
    //print_r($directions);

    // Show the total distance
    echo '<p><strong>Total distance:</strong> ' . $directions->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text . '</p>';


    ?>
<div id class="distance"></div>
```

The jQuery that inserts the value looks like below and it works perfectly. It inserts it as supposed but the php doesn't pass it to the array

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var someName = $('.um-field-postal_zip_code .um-field-value').text();
 $("input#hidden-input").attr("value", someName);

});
```

Comment: @PrashantTapase wow amazing, may you could help, instead being unconstructive. SleekGeek, i'll post my answer in a second.

Comment: What you mean by `echo value of an input field into an array`? Input field is HTML element, array is PHP element. Only way to communicate is posting form values back to server side using simple form submit or JS

Comment: @Tyralcori user posted very bad code. not have any logic to that code.

Comment: Yeah, may he posted bad code, but what gives you the right to being such offensive? You really could help! This is stackoverflow and not a talkshow.

Comment: post jquery code. so we can help properly

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
<!-- Set type -> Hidden, if you want to make that input field hidden.
You really should use better "names" for the input fields -->

<input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" name="from" value="">
</form>

<?php 

$params = array(
    'origin'        =>  $_POST['from'], // <- Now it should be empty, because nothing is inside
    'destination'   => um_user('postal_zip_code'),
    'sensor'        => 'true', // If you write 'false' it's still true, because the string is filled. Please use correct bools like true / false without the quotes // 'sensor' => true 
    'units'         => 'imperial'
); 
?>
```

You also need something to "send" or "activate" the form.

```
<input type="submit" name="sendForm" value="Send Form"/>
```

So the input form looks like:

```
<form method="post">
<!-- Set type -> Hidden, if you want to make that input field hidden.
You really should use better "names" for the input fields -->

<input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" name="from" value="">
<input type="submit" name="sendForm" value="Send Form"/>
</form>
```

Let me know, if you need more help!

Comment: where is the submit button?  how `$_post['from ']` will get value of input?

Comment: Oh you was faster than me, but yeah. I've edited a sec. ago. (Thank you, for being constructive this time!!)

Comment: Yeah, that is okay. It should be filled, if you take the id as selector like `$('#hidden-input').val()`.

Comment: But you need something to activate the form, so the $_POST fields gets filled. You can hide the button and let him fade in, if it's done, or auto-submit without the user click. But if the form was'nt activated, you can't access the POST values.

Answer (score 0):

### html

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage.php">
   <input id="hidden-input" name="from" value="">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_button">
</form>
```

#### php

```
<?php 
//if your form is submitted fill the array
if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])){
   $params = array(
      'origin'        =>  $_POST['from'],
      'destination'   => 'postal_zip_code',
      'sensor'        => 'true',
      'units'         => 'imperial'
   );

   //print array 
   foreach($params as $index=>$value){
     print $index." :".$value;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: I inserted a value by default with jQuery. It doesn't need a button.

Comment: but in a html form you have to submit to be able to use the form values later on your code, without submitting your values are lost.

Comment: See the situation here. I want the users to see the distance from the matches the moment they see theem. E.g Miss A lives 45 miles from you

Answer (score 0):

You can not fetch data from form without refresh of page. Actually you are trying to fetch data from hidden input which is coming from jquery.

First remove form html and make ajax call

You need to set ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var someName = $('.um-field-postal_zip_code .um-field-value').text();

if(!someName==''){//check somename is blank or not
//make ajax call
   $.ajax({url: "url of your php code", 
    data : 'someName',
    type : 'post',
    success: function(result){

        }});
}
});
```

In php file fetch data using `$_post`

```
echo $data = $_post['data'];//this is your origin
```

Now continue with your code

```
$params = array(
        'origin'        =>  $data,
        'destination'   => um_user('postal_zip_code'),
        'sensor'        => 'true',
        'units'         => 'imperial'
    );
$params_string='';
    // Join parameters into URL string
    foreach($params as $var => $val){
        $params_string .= '&' . $var . '=' . urlencode($val);  
    }

// Request URL
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?".ltrim($params_string, '&');

// Make our API request
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Parse the JSON response
$directions = json_decode($return);

//echo"<pre>";
//print_r($directions);

// Show the total distance
echo '<p><strong>Total distance:</strong> ' . $directions->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text . '</p>';
```

Comment: Read properly and what your are not understood that ask me. I am ready to answer.

Comment: did u get `$data`? then my work is finish. check ur script

Comment: you cant make jsfiddle... if there is php.

Comment: why dont you make demo on your server and share link with me. Try your self because i already given u hint.